# One device, many users fingerprint authentication

Tags: android, security

I'm trying to find a way to support the following scenario with fingerprint scan authentication.  I work on an app that is used in an enterprise setting, where a single Android device is likely to be shared by many users.  The current fingerprint scan APIs seem to follow a model where a user registers their fingerprint with the device, and then the fingerprint scan library basically just verifies that the fingerprint being scanned matches some known fingerprint stored locally in the device.  This model is incompatible with my use case, since each of my users may pick up a different Android device each time they need to use the app.  And each device may be used by multiple users.

Are there any ideas for overcoming this problem?  I'm thinking along the lines of getting some kind of hash or other unique identifier from the fingerprint scanner, which I could then store in my central database, and each user authentication attempt can be authenticated against this central server.  But sadly, it looks like neither Google's api nor vendor specific sdks allow this behavior.

Suggestions/insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If a device has a fingerprint sensor, a user can enroll one or more fingerprints and then use their fingerprints to unlock the device and perform other tasks.

Android uses the Fingerprint Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) to connect to a vendor-specific library and fingerprint hardware, e.g. a fingerprint sensor.